# GCP port forwarding via firewall

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, portforwarding

I have a VPC on GCP with a bastion host that has a public IP.
I am trying to connect from my local machine which is behind a firewall to an instance on a specific port behind the bastion server.

SSH works via bastion, ports are open between instances of GCP within the VPC.

I am trying to create port forwarding from my local machine to bastion to zookeeper on port 2181.

I have setup Ip tables however i just lose the packets somewhere on the way if doing a tcptraceroute.

Scenario is as follows:

Local machine -> Firewall -> Bastion -> Zookeeper

SSH connection from Local machine to Zookeeper(192.168.80.11) works (via Bastion)

My Configuration is as follows:

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2181 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.80.11:2181`

`sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`

Its just not work, what am i doing wrong?

My Ip tables have some weird entries tho:

---

```
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [83590:46593196]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon May 11 09:33:24 2020
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Mon May 11 09:33:24 2020
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [130202:45658294]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [83590:46593196]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon May 11 09:33:24 2020
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Mon May 11 09:33:24 2020
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [130202:45658294]
:INPUT ACCEPT [130201:45657860]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [83590:46593196]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [83593:46593358]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon May 11 09:33:24 2020
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Mon May 11 09:33:24 2020
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [234:14414]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2181 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.80.11:2181
:INPUT ACCEPT [233:13980]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [126:8408]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [126:8408]
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon May 11 09:33:24 2020
```

Comment: Have you checked the firewall rules in GCP to be sure they allow the connection from your local machine. I would attempt ssh from local to bastion, and edit firewall rules in GCP to allow an external connection.

Comment: Yes firewall is open, access is available to both jump server and the hosts behind in the vpc. 

Firewall has full access on all ports from both instances and the firewall. Checking tcpdump on port 2181 works to jump and from jump to server. Somehow when packet originates from behind firewall it goes to jump server but does not get forwarded

Comment: From the description you just gave me, it seems like ip forwarding is not on, you can check out this link [1] (https://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/) that will show you how to check that.